# The variables are null although initialized

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, nullpointerexception

This is an autotest:

```
public class BaseClass {
    protected ChromeDriver chromeDriver;
    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\zarip\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER"));
    chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @AfterEach
    public void after() {
        chromeDriver.quit();
    }
}

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions; 
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; 
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest; 
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ArgumentsSource; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; import pages.*;
public class Tests extends BaseClass {
@ParameterizedTest
@ArgumentsSource(BankPageFactory.class)
public void bank(int sale, int purchase) {
    String googleLink = "https://www.google.com/";
    String searchWord = "Открытие";
    chromeDriver.get(googleLink);
    GooglePageBeforeSearch pageBeforeSearch = new GooglePageBeforeSearch(chromeDriver);
    pageBeforeSearch.find(searchWord);


    Task2GglPageAfterSearch pageAfterSearch = new Task2GglPageAfterSearch(chromeDriver);
    pageAfterSearch.find();

    BankPageFactory bankPageFactory = new BankPageFactory(chromeDriver);
    bankPageFactory.find();

    for (WebElement web : bankPageFactory.getSaleResults()) {
        System.out.println(web.getText());
    }
    for (WebElement web : bankPageFactory.getPurchaseResults()) {
        System.out.println(web.getText());
    }
    System.out.println(bankPageFactory.getSaleResults() + " saleResults");
    System.out.println(bankPageFactory.getPurchaseResults() + " Purchase");

    Assertions.assertTrue(sale > purchase, "Sale rate is more than purchase rate");
    }
}

import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext; 
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments; 
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ArgumentsProvider; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class BankPageFactory implements ArgumentsProvider { 
    protected ChromeDriver chromeDriver;
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@href='https://www.open.ru/exchange-person?from=main_page'][contains(text(), \"Все курсы\")]")
    WebElement allCurrencies;
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "(//td[@class='card-rates-table__cell card-rates-table__sale large-text'])[position() < 3]")
    List<WebElement> saleRate;
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "(//td[@class='card-rates-table__cell card-rates-table__purchase large-text'])[position() < 3]")
    List<WebElement> purchaseRate;
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//span[@class='open-ui-button-text'][contains(text(), 'Закрыть')]")
    WebElement cookies;
    
    //    WebElement allCurrencies; 
    //    WebElement cookies; 
    //    List<WebElement> saleRate; 
    //    List<WebElement> purchaseRate;
    
    public BankPageFactory(ChromeDriver chromeDriver) {
        this.chromeDriver = chromeDriver;
    //        this.allCurrencies = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://www.open.ru/exchange-person?from=main_page'][contains(text(), "Все курсы")]")); 
    //        this.saleRate = chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath("(//td[@class='card-rates-table__cell card-rates-table__sale large-text'])[position() < 3]")); 
    //        this.purchaseRate = chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath("(//td[@class='card-rates-table__cell card-rates-table__purchase large-text'])[position() < 3]")); 
    //        this.cookies = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='open-ui-button-text'][contains(text(), 'Закрыть')]")); 
    PageFactory.initElements(chromeDriver, this); }

public BankPageFactory() {
}

public void find() {
    if (allCurrencies.isEnabled()) {
        System.out.println(allCurrencies.getText());
    } else {
        System.out.println(allCurrencies + " is NOT enabled");
    }

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 180);
    while (!allCurrencies.isDisplayed()) {
        allCurrencies = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://www.open.ru/exchange-person?from=main_page'][contains(text(), \"Все курсы\")")));
    }
    cookies.click();
    Actions actions = new Actions(chromeDriver);
    actions.moveToElement(allCurrencies);
    actions.perform();

    allCurrencies.click();
    }

    public List<WebElement> getSaleResults() {
    return saleRate;
    }

    public List<WebElement> getPurchaseResults() {
    return purchaseRate;
    }
    @Override
public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
    List<Arguments> argumentsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (WebElement web : getSaleResults()) {
        System.out.println(web.getText());
    }
    for (WebElement web : getPurchaseResults()) {
        System.out.println(web.getText());
    }


    if (getSaleResults() != null && getSaleResults() != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(saleRate.size(), purchaseRate.size()); i++) {
            argumentsList.add(Arguments.of(saleRate.get(i), purchaseRate.get(i)));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Variable saleRate and purchaseRate were not initialized correctly.");
    }
    System.out.println(argumentsList);
    return argumentsList.stream();
    }
}
```

The problem is as follows:

The variables saleRate and purchaseRate in class BankPageFactory were initialized as follows:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "(//td[@class='card-rates-table__cell card-rates-table__sale large-text'])[position() < 3]")
List<WebElement> saleRate;
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "(//td[@class='card-rates-table__cell card-rates-table__purchase large-text'])[position() < 3]")
List<WebElement> purchaseRate;
```

and I used PageFactory.initElements(chromeDriver, this); in constructor.
But when I refer to these 2 variables in the class, the following error comes out:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because the return value of "pages.BankPageFactory.getSaleResults()" is null

```
at pages.BankPageFactory.provideArguments(BankPageFactory.java:87)
at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.arguments(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:133)
at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$2(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:107)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:42)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Suppressed: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:281)
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$6(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.close(AbstractPipeline.java:323)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
    ... 53 more
```

I understand that initialization of a variable when using the @findBy annotation occurs only when this variable is accessed. And here is just such a case: I'm referring to the variables in the method public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext extensionContext), but get NullPointerException.

Can you explain what my mistake is? What ways out of this situation do you see?

as you can see, I tried to visually initialize variables in the constructor without the @findBy annotation. However, this did not bear fruit. I used getters instead of direct accesses to variables, but that didn't help either.

Comment: most likely this constructor `public BankPageFactory() {
}
` is called instead

Comment: I think you need to call a method on it for the findsby to run.  Try  saleRate.isEmpty(); return saleRate;

Comment: @njzk2 I think so too, but without an empty constructor, the parameterized test will not work because the "@ArgumentSource" annotation requires you to specify BankPageFactory.class , as a result, you need to write an empty constructor

Comment: all the more reasons to believe that this empty constructor is called. I'm not sure that `@ArgumentsSource` supports classes that don't have an empty constructor.

Comment: @njzk2, you're right. I had to use "@MethodSource" instead of "@ArgumentsSource"